# Using large arrays, I get "Access violation writing location" in a different place every time

Tags: c

For some reason (I guess the malloc) my code doesn't work after a random iteration.

Basically I'm supposed to read code from a file and put it in an array of vertexes. 
A vertex looks like this: `v  -0.11459 0.100413 0.298243`.

- num_of_vertexes=2108.
- Visual Studio 2019.

```
Vertex* vertexes = (Vertex*)malloc(sizeof(Vertex*)*num_of_vertexes);
for (int i = 0;i < num_of_vertexes;i++) {
    vertexes[i].x = 0; //Crashes here at a random i>900
    vertexes[i].y = 0;
    vertexes[i].z = 0;
}

typedef struct {
    float x; // Coordinates of Vertex
    float y;
    float z;
} Vertex;
```

Comment: First your code is incomplete, and second it looks as if you are allocating space for pointers to a Vertex, but not for the Vertices themselves.

Comment: In general, there should be one less `*` in the argument to `sizeof` than the type that you're assigning to. So it should be `sizeof(Vertex)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your size calculation is wrong - you're multiplying the number of elements in the array by the size of a `Vertex*` (a Vertex pointer) instead of the size of a `Vertex`:

```c
Vertex* vertexes = (Vertex*) malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * num_of_vertexes);
/* Here -----------------------------------------^ */
```

Comment: Thank you very much! can you clarify though why do you cast it to a pointer but allocate a size of a Vertex?

Comment: Let's try to avoid downvoting correct and accepted answers +1.